# CentOS: Postgres 11 yum repo missing repomd.xml (Errno 14 404 Not Found)

Tags: postgresql, centos7, yum

I'm trying to install Postgres 11 on an EC2 CentOS 7 server but can't get past the Postgres yum repo. I try to install the repo:

```
yum install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm
```

and get [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found for the URL https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-2-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml.

The error is correct - that URL does NOT exist. rhel-2* doesn't exist in https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/. How can I work around what appears to be a yum definition bug? Is there a more valid mirror somewhere?

[image: yum install fails to add repo because of (valid) 404 error]
[image: yum repolist shows same 404 error]

Comment: Try; `rpm -ivh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm` You appear to be trying to use the direct url of the rpm as a repo. If you want the actual PGSQL rpm and have no dep issues try; `rpm -ivh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/postgresql11-server-11.1-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: @user3788685 `rpm -ivh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm` has the same problem - running `yum repolist` afterwards shows 404 Not Found for repomd.xml with an identical URL to the one in the main post. I don't have the dependencies for postgresql11-server at this point. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you enabled the repo? Look in `/etc/yum.repos.d/<whatever it named the new repo.conf` then look for the line `enabled=0` and change the `0` to a `1` using just the rpm command on its own shouldn't involve yum at all so not sure why you still show that error.

Comment: @user3788685 yes, pgdg-11-centos.repo shows 'enabled=1':
`cat /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-11-centos.repo

[pgdg11]

name=PostgreSQL 11 $releasever - $basearch

baseurl=https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-$releasever-$basearch

enabled=1`

Answer (score 5):

For new following by steps:

1. Go to https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages/#pg91 find and copy link of "CentOS 7 - x86_64"

   https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
2. run:

   sudo rpm -Uvh https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-7-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

Then, this issue will be fixed.

Comment: I do not get your "For new ..." phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem on Amazon Linux 2.

This worked for me:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh https://yum.postgresql.org/11/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/pgdg-centos11-11-2.noarch.rpm
sudo sed -i "s/rhel-\$releasever-\$basearch/rhel-7.5-x86_64/g" "/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-11-centos.repo"
sudo yum install postgresql11
```

Found the correct 2nd statement here:
https://installvirtual.com/how-to-install-postgresql-11-on-amazon-ec2-amazon-linux/